# How do I make git use the editor of my choice on Windows instead of Notepad.exe?

Tags: windows, git, sublimetext3

I'm trying to get git use Sublime Text for commit messages and interactive rebases, but whenever I try to run `git rebase --interactive` or `git commit`, the editor that comes up is Notepad.

I've configured Sublime Text 3 as my editor by running

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe' -n -w"
```

to tell subl.exe to open a new window and to wait for the output. I've confirmed that my `editor` setting is set correctly in my .gitconfig:

```
editor = 'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe' -n -w
```

In addtion, I've tried running the `subl.exe` command from the git bash prompt by itself (on a text file) and verified that Sublime Text does open a new window for the file and waits until the window is closed before returning to the prompt.

What else should I be looking at? It seems like no matter what I do, git tries to use notepad.exe.

Comment: I use Notepad++ and the following line in ~/.gitconfig works for me: `editor = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was that notepad was configured as my editor in the repository's own config. Going into the `.git` folder in the repo itself and removing notepad from the `config` file there caused git to recognize the global configuration once again.